# Ruby -- group items by day with shifted beginning of the day

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, datetime, dictionary

I have a dictionary as such:

```
{"status": "ok", "data": [{"temp": 22, "datetime": "20160815-0330"}]}
```

`20160815-0330` means `2016-08-15 03:30`. I want to group by **day** and calculate min and max `temp`, but the day should **start at 09:00 and end at 08:59**. How could I do that?

Here is my code:

```
@results = @data['data'].group_by { |d| d['datetime'].split('-')[0] }.map do |date, values|
  [date, {
    min_temp: values.min_by { |value| value['temp'] || 0 }['temp'],
    max_temp: values.max_by { |value| value['temp'] || 0 }['temp']
  }]
end

#=> {"20160815"=>{:min_temp =>12, :max_temp =>34}}
```

I works, but the starting point is 00:00, not 09:00.

Comment: Does it start from 0900 and end at 0859 the next day?

Comment: Yes that's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use a timezone trick:

```
def adjust_datetime(str)
  DateTime.parse(str.sub('-', '') + '+0900').utc.strftime('%Y%m%d')
end

data.group_by { |d| adjust_datetime(d['datetime']) }
```

Here is an explanation:

```
str = '20160815-0330'
str = str.sub('-', '')   #=> '201608150330'
str = str + '+0900'      #=> '201608150330+0900'
dt = DateTime.parse(str) #=> Mon, 15 Aug 2016 03:30:00 +0900
dt = dt.utc              #=> 2016-08-14 18:30:00 UTC
dt.strftime('%Y%d%m')    #=> '20160814'
```

Comment: Thanks Danil. It seems to be adding on 9hrs is this right?

Comment: Data output isn't matching to what it should. So it's add 9hrs to each iteration? Or taking the date time start time or 0000 and adding 0900 to it? I guess I'm meaning beginning_of_day().

Comment: I guess what I'm asking is, is there anyway to change the beginning_of_day from 0:00 to 9:00 and end_of_day from 23:59:59 to 8:59.

Comment: This is the right answer. My fault for not recognising that the start time needed to be 9:01, that why the data was getting thrown out.